# TASM вывод числа

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Вводятся числа в программу, после чего с ними происходит математика. При выводе итогового числа в консоль получаю различные смайлики

[image: пример вывода]

Как можно это исправить? ниже код файла .asm

```
model small
.stack 100h
.data
x db 0
a db 0
y1 db ?
y2 db ?
y db ?
ySmall db 0
message1 db 13,10,"Введите x: $"
flag db 0
.code
start:
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    mov ah,9h
    lea dx,message1
    int 21h

    mov ah,1
    int 21h

input:
    mov ah,1
    int 21h

AfterPress:
    cmp al,13
    je endInput
    sub al,30h
    mov bl,al
    mov bh,10
    mov al,x
    xor ah,ah
    mul bh
    add al,bl
    mov x,al
    loop input

endInput:

    mov ah,2
    mov dl,x
    int 21h

    mov ah,10h
    int 16h

    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h
end start
```

Comment: Сам файл с кодом в какой кодировке? Может нужно кодировку файла в консольную`cp866` перевести. У вас судя по двухбайтовости каждого русского символа может `UTF-16` какая-нибудь? Козябрами у вас слово "Введите" напечаталось, из-за него нужно кодировку поменять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ```
   message1 db 13,10,"Введите x: $"
   ```

С тем ничего не наделаете, для понятного текста на выводном экране TASM нужно использовать **только ASCII знаки `20h`-`7fh`** (английский алфавит, цифры, специальные символы):

```
   message1 db 13,10,"Enter x: $"
```

---

2. ```
   mov ah,2
   mov dl,x
   int 21h
   ```

У вас в переменной `x` результат, очевидно одна цифра (т.к. `int 21h` для `ah=2` выводит только один знак).

Но эта цифра *в бинарной форме* (`0`-`9`), а **не в знаковой** (`"0`"-`"9"`, «человеческой»).

В ASCII таблице знаки `"0`"-`"9"` кодируются как числа `30h`-`39h`, значит, для вывода в человеческой форме нужно добавить `30h`:

```
   mov ah,2
   mov dl,x
   add dl,30h     ; здесь добавлено
   int 21h
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо)

Comment: "С тем ничего не наделаете, для понятного текста на выводном экране TASM нужно использовать только ASCII знаки 20h-ffh (английский алфавит, цифры, специальные символы):" - кириллица вполне нормально выводится, если сохранить исходник в кодировке cp866.

Comment: @insolor, в GUI Turbo Assembler невозможно, только знаки 20h-7fh, не возможно это изменить.

Comment: @MarianD это проблема конкретно этого IDE (и возможно поставляемой с ним сборки DOSBOX), у ассемблера TASM такого ограничения нет.